# Cairo fill a polygon with a hatch pattern

Tags: haskell, gtk, drawing, cairo

Is it possible with cairo to fill a box or a polygon with a hatch (or arbitrary) pattern like below ? I didn't find informatinos in the cairo documentation or hackage.

[image: hatch pattern]

- Are there built-in pattern in cairo ?
- What are the functions to fill with patterns ?

I'm using haskell but a snippet in any language would be helpful.

Comment: Not a full answer, but: perhaps you can [clip](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cairo-0.13.0.6/docs/Graphics-Rendering-Cairo.html#v:clip) the shape you want to fill, then draw your pattern overtop some easily-computable larger region than the shape covers.

Comment: This seems to do something similar by creating a pattern from an image and then tiling it into a shape: http://cairographics.org/samples/imagepattern/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cairo_pattern_t *pattern = create_stipple ("lightgrey", (guchar *)stipple_data);
cairo_matrix_init_scale (&matrix, 1.0, 1.0);
cairo_pattern_set_matrix (pattern, &matrix);
some_shape = GOO_CANVAS_RECT (goo_canvas_rect_new (GOO_CANVAS_ITEM (group), 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, "fill-pattern", pattern, "visibility", GOO_CANVAS_ITEM_INVISIBLE, NULL));
cairo_pattern_destroy (pattern);
```

Taken from one of my pet projects [oregano @ github](https://github.com/drahnr/oregano/blob/master/src/sheet/rubberband.c)

ALso have a look at the [cairo API reference](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-cairo-pattern-t.html#cairo-pattern-t) which also covers generic pattern API

Comment: I don't see the string "stipple" anywhere on the linked page, by the way.

Comment: What stipple? The stipple is achieved by defining a patch of 8x8 size with manually defined data as done in oregano. `create_stipple` is a custom function doing exactly that as linked.

Comment: You give a link and describe it as having "stipple details". But this is not obviously the case, as the link doesn't mention stipple at all. Perhaps you should change the link to point to documentation for your library, or update the description of the link to say what you expect people to find there.

Comment: the link to the oregano file. The link to cairo pattern just is the _reference_ of what cairo already provides.